# Delete an oracle-user with single quotes in the username

Tags: oracle, oracle9i

Through a faulty script I have created a user with single quotes around his username (i.e. his username is 'username', not username) on an Oracle 9i system. Now I want to remove that user. Neither "DROP USER 'username'" nor "DROP USER \'username\'" nor "DROP USER (SELECT username FROM all_users where user_id = 123)" worked. How do I get rid of that user?

Comment: don't forget about capitalization, too

Answer (score 4):

```
create user "'bla'" identified by bla;

drop user "'bla'";
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me:

SQL> DROP USER "'username'" CASCADE;
DROP USER "'username'" CASCADE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
 
ORA-06512: at line 7

Comment: Works for me. Tested on Oracle 11g though. 
SQL> create user "'username'" identified by bla; 
User created. 
SQL> drop user "'username'"; 
User dropped.

Comment: You got a recursive SQL error - just guessing, maybe it has something to do with an object owned by the user? Not sure. What happens if you don't specify the CASCADE option?

Comment: OK. Are you logged in with the SYSDBA role? Also, check out this link: http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=844287&tstart=45

Comment: The ORA-00933 might indicate a bug somewhere - when it cascades the drop to other objects or references, the code cannot cope with a username with quotes in it. This is just a guess. You may need to set trace on the session to see what recursive SQL is being run.

Comment: Looks like you're not the first to come across this problem: http://www.ora-code.com/bbs/View?grp=Oracle_List&msg=dce6ff529faca7bff46ca30d117401c2

Comment: A comment in this thread: http://kr.forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=662605 leads me to ask, are there any system triggers enabled in your database (possibly to do with replication)?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Oracle's Documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements008.htm#i27570)...

> "A quoted identifier begins and ends
>   with double quotation marks ("). If
>   you name a schema object using a
>   quoted identifier, then you must use
>   the double quotation marks whenever
>   you refer to that object."

So this...

```
DROP USER "username" CASCADE;
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post, but for anyone stumbling across this as the result of a search on this problem - the issue appears to be that a database trigger is firing on drop user.
I've posted the solution I found for Oracle XE ( probably the same for other 10g releases) 
[here](http://mikesmithers.wordpress.com/2010/02/17/dropping-quoted-users-%E2%80%93-why-sometimes-oracle-cant-bear-to-say-goodbye/)

Hope someone finds this useful,

Mike

Answer (score 1):

Try `DROP USER "'username'"` or `DROP USER ''username''`. (Note that those last quotes are all single quotes)

Comment: the first idea is correct (double quotes), the second (single quotes) won't work (I was wondering that myself and tried it)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Oracle off-hand, but might you try enclosing it in double quotes?

(I'll delete this answer if its wrong)

Answer (score 0):

The following code might help you :

```
declare 

   sel_username varchar2(30); 
   r_user_id    varchar2(30); 
   r_username   varchar2(30); 
   user_cmd     varchar2(200); 

BEGIN
/* 
   This procedure will delete a single user_id and can be used to delete a user 
   with none displayable characters in the name 

   **Replace** the user_id  in this script to that you want to delete !! 

   Author: Ulrich Henkenjohann  -  March 2010 / tested on ORACLE 10.2.0.4 

*/      
-- select the username for a special user_id. Ther username may contain none displayed characters

   select username into sel_username from dba_users where user_id = 34; 
   select user_id, username into r_user_id , r_username from dba_users where username = sel_username ; 
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Selected user: ' || r_user_id || ' ' || r_username); 

-- If a test is needed, an alter passwort command may be usefull 
-- user_cmd := 'ALTER USER "' || r_username || '" IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORDX '; 

-- Drop the selected user 

   user_cmd := 'DROP USER "' || r_username || '" CASCADE '; 
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Executing user_cmd: ' || user_cmd ); 
   execute immediate user_cmd ; 

END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Once again with better format:

```
declare 

   sel_username varchar2(30); 

   r_user_id    varchar2(30); 

   r_username   varchar2(30); 

   user_cmd     varchar2(200); 

BEGIN

/* 

   This procedure will delete a single userid and can be used to delete a user 
   with none displayable characters in the name 

   **Replace the user_id  in this script !!** 

   Author: Ulrich Henkenjohann  -  March 2010 / tested on ORACLE 10.2.0.4 

*/      
-- select the username for a special user_id. Ther username may contain none displayed characters

   select username into sel_username from dba_users where user_id = 34; 

   select user_id, username into r_user_id , r_username from dba_users where username = sel_username ; 

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Selected user: ' || r_user_id || ' ' || r_username); 

-- If a test is needed, an alter passwort command may be usefull 

-- user_cmd := 'ALTER USER "' || r_username || '" IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORDX '; 

-- Drop the selected user 

   user_cmd := 'DROP USER "' || r_username || '" CASCADE '; 

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Executing user_cmd: ' || user_cmd ); 

   execute immediate user_cmd ; 

END;
/
```